# Natural Transformation confusion

Tags: category-theory

This comes from *Categories for the Working Mathematician*. The problem is, "show that evaluation, that is, $e : X^S \times S \rightarrow X$ given be $e(h, s) = h(s)$ is a natural transformation." The part that confuses me is that natural transformations are between functors, and neither $X^S \times S$ nor $X$ look like a functor. I imagine the right functor should be the identity, and the functor on the left should be defined by $X \mapsto X^S \times S$ for objects, and $f \mapsto (f \circ -) \times 1_S$ for arrows. Am I correct in my assumption? And is this kind of notation (representing a functor by what it does to objects) common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I imagine the right functor should be the identity, and the functor on the left should be defined by

Yes, you are right.

$\require{AMScd}$You can actually prove two things:

1. Given a morphism $f : X\to Y$ the square
   $$
   \begin{CD}
   X^S\times S @>e_{X,(S)}>> X \\
   @Vf^S\times SVV @VVfV\\
   Y^S\times S @>>e_{Y,(S)}> Y 
   \end{CD}
   $$ commutes.
2. Given a morphism $u : S\to T$ the square
   $$
   \begin{CD}
   X^T\times S @>X^T\times u>> X^T\times T \\
   @VX^u\times SVV @VVe_{X,(T)}V\\
   X^S\times S @>>e_{X,(S)}> X 
   \end{CD}
   $$ commutes.

The first condition is naturality; the second is called [dinaturality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinatural_transformation).

Note that all these things are true in a cartesian closed category (but the proof is equally instructive when you do it in $\bf Set$).